# How to update a foreign key's attribute after creation of object in Django Model

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a REST API using Django that has two models that relate to each other: `Item` and `Attribute`. An Item has `Attribute` as a foreign key. The `Attribute` model has a field called `number_of_uses` which stores the number of items that attribute has associated it with. I wanted to know how I can update that number on the creation of a new `Item.` How can I update the field after the creation of the item, but before the API returns a response to the caller?

Answer (score 0):

First of, are you sure this is One-To-Many?

Maybe check out this? [model.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods). You can override the save method to increase the counter of the attribute.

Another possibility is to create a [property field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods) for `number_of_uses`. Something like this:

```py
class Attribute(models.Model):
    # fields

    @property
    def number_of_uses(self):
        return Item.objects.filter(attribute = self).count()
                               # or attribute__field = self.field
```

This can also be serialized and is always accurate.